# What's the result of transferring your Pokemon to the professor?

Tags: pokemon-go

If you tap on one of your Pokemon in the inventory a wild menu appears! Swipe the page to go to the bottom to find that there's a "transfer" button. Tapping it yields a menu with the following text,

> You can't take it back after it's transferred to the professor. Do you really want to transfer **[pokemon species you tapped on]** to the Professor?"

What's the point of this?

Comment: Unlke in regular pokemon games (where you level up and evolve pokemon through battle) in pokemon go you use species-specific candy which you get primerally from catching duplicates. Transferring to the professor lets you clean up the heap of duplicate pokemon and get a little more candy.